# Simple popup as a graphic with a closing button

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I need to code a image that appears as a popup with the option to close it with a button. I already have the button style, I just need your help on how to code it together? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Plz add some code

Comment: Well your requirement is quite simple but you didn't add any code. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple script for you with pure js. If you find this helpful. Select my answer and give +1.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.popup-img img').forEach(single=>{
  single.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    let img = e.target;
    img.classList.add('popped');
    let back = document.createElement('div');
    back.classList.add('img-popup');
    let close = document.createElement('span');
    close.classList.add('close');
    back.appendChild(close);
    document.body.appendChild(back);
    back.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
      back.classList.add('closed');
        img.classList.remove('popped');
      setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('.img-popup').remove();
      },500)
    })
  })
  
})
```

```css
.img-popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.95);
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: .5s ease;
}
.img-popup.closed {
  transform: scale(0);
}
.img-popup .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.img-popup .close:before, .img-popup .close:after {content: '';width: 24px;height: 2px;background: #fff;position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;}
.img-popup .close:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: left;
    top: 13px;
    left: 13px;
}
.img-popup .close:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: right;
    top: 13px;
    right: 10px;
    left: initial;
}
img.popped {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    max-height: 85vh;
    max-width: 85vw;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transition: .5s ease;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/cyESoU/img1.jpg" width="200">
  <div class="popup-img"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/cyESoU/img1.jpg" width="250"></div>
</div>
```